# Why the Object Name is Reset When Deleting a Message Call

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm using Visio to draw a sequence diagram. I have an issue where when I delete a message call from the diagram, the object of the deleted message call is reset.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently naming objects in sequence diagram need be done by double-click on the object where a popup window appear to fill in the details of the object.

I was trying to name object by directly typing the name on the keyboard without using double-click.